# Como mudar um state de um component no react navigation

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Eu preciso mudar um state dentro de uma função do react navigation, esse state vai alterar um comportamento no component

```
function TabOneNavigator({navigation}) { 
    React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {

      if(global.webview.startUrl != global.webview.props.source.uri){
        //aqui eu preciso chamar o metodo resetWebViewToInitialUrl()
        //que está no componente
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="Perfil"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'IzyJob' }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

eu estou tentando mudar o state do componente quando o botão do react navigator for clicado, esse é o código do meu componente

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  this.state = {
    key: 1,
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
  };
  
  resetWebViewToInitialUrl = () => {
    this.setState({
      key: this.state.key + 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <WebView 
    key={ this.state.key }
    ref={(ref) => { global.webview = ref; }}
    source={{ uri: this.state.url }} 
    onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
    style={{ marginTop: 0 }} />;
  }
}
```

Eu já tentei usando props mas não chega na função do navigator, também tentei criando um global mas ai eu não consigo alterar o state

Answer (score 0):

Quando utiliza o [react-navigation](/questions/tagged/react-navigation) e precisa de tratar de operações relacionados deve utilizar na sua documentação a guia [Navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events), nesses eventos pode ser escrito soluções de atualizações como está pedindo na sua pergunta.

Na documentação tem **4** eventos:

- [focus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) - Este evento é emitido quando a tela entra em
- [focus blur](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) - Este evento é emitido quando a tela fica desfocada
- [beforeRemove](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) - Este evento é emitido quando o usuário está saindo da tela, há uma chance de impedir que o usuário saia
- [state (advanced)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) - Este evento é emitido quando o estado do navegador muda

e já também existe os [Hooks](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/) para isso como exemplo da própria documentação:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(data));

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```

<sup>*Código retirado do link:* [Triggering an action with the useFocusEffect hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook)</sup>

---

No seu código eu pude perceber que o evento está em um componente e é chamado em outro componente, acredito que o você tenha que usar ou um [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) ou [Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) para que isso fique disponível globalmente no seu código e com os eventos acima explicado utilizando o `focus` possa contemplar a sua duvida.